Create ROM using Logic Elements vs Block RAM
In FPGAs, one can create a ROM using logic elements and also using block RAM. When using block RAM, we would follow the tool vendor's process to create a ROM.
For Quartus, this means that we specify that a memory block be initialized using a .mif file for example but there are other ways. In this case, the configuration bit stream shall write values into the memory block and since the data cannot be changed from that point on, we have a ROM from block RAM.
When logic elements are used to create the ROM, everything is written in RTL like a look up table. If the ROM becomes too large, it could become critical path in the design and limit the fmax.
My question is, how does one decide if the ROM should be hard coded in RTL or should be implemented using block RAM instead?


When using block RAM, we would follow the tool vendor's process to create a ROM.

is not required.  While that process is one way to create a ROM lookup, the tools also look for certain behavior patterns that describe read-only table lookup and also generate block ROM.
Now, when you describe a block ROM in RTL, there's more risk that the tool will fail to recognize the pattern and use logic elements instead.  So it helps to structure the code according to a template.
See for example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/341162/1743

There is no one "right" answer. It's always about your project's constraints and requirements.
If you can spend a blockram for a rom, or you just testing the idea - use a blockram, it's easy and timings won't fluctuate depending on the rom content.
If you can't afford a blockram because of the resources count on a target FPGA selected for a product - you attempt to squeeze it into logic elements. Smallish data sets are good fit for distributed ram (MLAB, SLICEM, etc). Occasionally you even have to fight the compiler which did infer the unwanted type of implementation and failed to fit the design into the target FPGA.
If your data is really large - you require a blockram and select different FPGA for the product, which can allow that resource expenditures.
So in the end you must check what are your needs for storage capacity, what are the resources limits on a selected fpga, how fast are possible implementations, and then you make a choice within acceptable limits.
